# newtonsoft json deserializer not working for property with no set

Tags: c#, json

I'm facing a null exception when de-serializing the class below:

```
[Serializable]
public class myClass
{
    public IList<string> ResidentialAddressToPrint
        {
            get
            {
                var list = new List<string>();
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ResidentialAddress.AddressLine1))
                    list.Add(ResidentialAddress.AddressLine1);
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ResidentialAddress.AddressLine2))
                    list.Add(ResidentialAddress.AddressLine2);
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ResidentialAddress.Suburb))
                    list.Add(ResidentialAddress.Suburb);
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ResidentialAddress.State))
                    list.Add(ResidentialAddress.State);
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ResidentialAddress.Postcode))
                    list.Add(ResidentialAddress.Postcode);
                return list;
            }
}



[Serializable]
    public class RegisterRebateAddressModel
    {
        public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }
        public string AddressLine2 { get; set; }
        public string Suburb { get; set; }
        public string State { get; set; }
        public string Postcode { get; set; }
    }


*Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Error getting value from 'myClass'. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
at myClass.get_ResidentialAddressToPrint()*
```

Can someone clarify below:

1. Does newtonsoft requires the mandatory Set property?
2. Also noticed it fails for private set; property. Is this feature by design.
3. What's the best way to solve this issue as we have many properties with no setter.

Comment: How are you deserializing? The exception doesn't match the behavior you've described.  Depending on how you are calling deserialize will determine the answer to #3.  That said, the answers to #1 and #2 are ***yes*** and ***yes*** respectively.

Comment: This way David L, JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(data, settings); where TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All

Comment: One way to solve #3 would be to create separate classes (ApiModel classes or some such if that's the purpose of these) with getters and setters, just used for deserialisation, and perform some mapping to initialise them

Comment: So we definitely can't deserialize property with just Get only? Any option to get this working without having to add settter?